# Java script how to construct an object using variables

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working on **express.js** framework and **sequlize.js** orm.

I get the region and the type from the back-end.

Using those two variables I want to construct an object to pass to the sequlize orm.

```js
        let region_id = req.swagger.params.region_id.value;
        let type = req.swagger.params.type.value;

        console.log("REGION", region_id) // will output 4,5,6,... etc
        console.log("TYPE", type) // will output is_lunch,is_dinner,... etc
```

That was my variables.

This is my object

```html
const prepared_query = {
            where:{
            },
            attributes: ['price'],
            include: [{
                model: db.restaurants,
                attributes: ['region_id'],
                where: {
                    region_id: ''
                }
            }]
        }

        prepared_query.include[0].where.region_id = region_id;
        prepared_query.where[type] = true;
```

```
prepared_query.include[0].where.region_id = region_id;
```

successfully replaced the region_id as 4. **but**

```
prepared_query.where[type] = true;
```

is not gives me `is_lunch:true'` instead it gives me `Cannot set property 'is_lunch'  of undefined`

**HOW DO I ACHIEVE THIS USING JAVA SCRIPT?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: @NisargShah I don't think so.

Comment: You should try doing `prepared_query[type] = true;` Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I update my question

Comment: @NisargShah Thanks a lot. I din't heard this thing before =)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.

```
prepared_query.include[0].where.region_id = region_id;
prepared_query[type] = true;

object.property = value;
{
    //static
    "property": value;
}
object[property] = value;
{
    //dynamic
    [property]: value;
}
```

read this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

Comment: Thanks a lot. I din't heard this thing before =)

Comment: @PathumSamararathna this is async problem, so you use `await - async` async ajaxfunction() ..

res = await getResponse()

Answer (score 0):

I didn't set anything to the `prepared_query.where` was the problem here.

```
    prepared_query.where = {};
    prepared_query.where[type] = true
```

Gives me the correct output.